# Very slow Internet speed after switching to a Netgear CG3100D-2BPAUS

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, usb-network-adapter

I’ve been having stable internet ever since I’ve gotten a [Belkin n300 wireless USB adapter](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F9L1002/). However, after switching from Optus to Telstra internet, the download speeds dropped to below 0.5mbits/s from the  usual 20-30mbit/s.

All my other devices are working fine and have no problems with download speed, except for my computer. I am wondering if I could change any adapter/router settings to fix the problem or if I should just buy a new adapter.

The router is a [Netgear CG3100D-2BPAUS](http://setuprouter.com/router/netgear/cg3100d-2/).

Edit: The problem seems to be coming from my pc. I've just swapped in an adapter from the fast desktop and the internet is still at the 0.5-2kbit/s range (the fast pc using the belkin adapter still has very fast internet). I am doing a virus scan to see if that is causing the problem but it might just be the router settings. Are there any settings that I can tweak?

Comment: In order to help you fix the problem we need more info, what brand and model number of router are you using?

Comment: Sure, the router is "NETGEAR cable home network gateway CG3100D-2BPAUS

Comment: You should edit your post and add this info.